# Should I use Node JS(Express framework) for creating a Web Site like UrbanClap(Something similar)?

Tags: node.js, backend

So I'm new to Node JS and express but while learning Node JS I came to know that it works on a single thread so I started wondering what if I wanted to create a Website for my portfolio which would be somewhat similar to urban clap, should I use Node JS in such case for back-end or should I use something like .NET technologies or something else?

Comment: this depend upon your skills if you're good at C# then go for the .NET and if you're good at Javascript then go for Node Js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it all depends on what you are comfortable with... I can tell you that nodeJS for backend is great, it's not perfect you will need to look after even loop blocks etc but if we are talking about a portfolio site, which probably won't get hundreds of clicks in a minute etc?

How much load you are expecting?

basically what i'm saying is that working with nodejs as backend can provide great results but if you are more comfortable with .net then go for that... single thread is not a problem you can use pm2 or something similar to spin up multiple instances of your application for example.

think about how much load you are expecting and what's better for u? is this a learning experience? then go for node, is this something u want to get up quickly so people can see the portfolio then go with whatever you are familiar with best...

Also, think about where you want to host the website and what technologies it supports etc...

In any case, do whatever is best for you